# How to name a Javascript Function specific to id of a div encapsulating it in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial View, which I am trying to load twice onto a cshtml file.

Now inside my partial View I have a javascript function as well. At this point, when I load my
cshtml onto the page, I will have two Javascript functions with same name.

I want to avoid this kind of scenario and name the Javascript function uniquely depending upon the Model which I am binding the Partial View to.

Please Not I could achieve the uniqueness for each control inside my partial by associating it with a parameter like "@Model.Id". But I am unable to apply the same kind of thing for uniqueness of Javascript function.

I am sorry for my Bad English. Kindly let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve scenario like that you can use `data-attribute`.

For example we have identical html code surrounded by a div, those div's had different id.

Each div will have a `data-attribute` and with jquery you can catch an event (Like Click)

Now Code Example

**HTML**

```
<div id="id1" data-attribute="doSomething">Element</div>
<div id="id2" data-attribute="doSomething">Element</div>
```

In your case those div represent the results coming from the partial view
also you can change the value store in the `id` attribute to come from your model something like `id="id@{Model.Id}"`

**JQuery**

```
$("div[data-attribute=doSomething]").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked element: " + $(this).prop("id")); 
});
```

[Fiddel Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9mfcq/)

I am using [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) of Jquery to achieve it

Note That you can achieve it also by defining a class attribute. 
But I think you should use this when you actually need a class otherwise use custom attribute like `data-value="something"`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having many functions with different names for each partial you could have a single javascript function which operates on each control. So for example you could assign a class to those controls and then write your function under the form of a [`jQuery plugin`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) attached to all controls with this classname.

Now the function could be declared inside a separate javascript file without mixing markup and javascript in a partial which is a bad design. The plugin could then be simply attached to all controls with this class with a standard jQuery syntax:

```
$(function() {
    $('.someClass').myFunction();
});
```

You could also use the HTML5 data-* attributes on your DOM elements to associate some metadata with them such as an unique identifier coming from your model. This metadata will then be accessible in your jQuery plugin.

For example:

```
<div class="someClass" data-id="@Model.Id">
    This is some div with associated metadata
</div>
```